# Generating Sample Data in any defined file format

Tags: testing

We receive sample data from clients in specific file formats and a set of specifications for the data which our software needs to handle. But the sample data provided does not cover all scenarios mentioned in the specifications. This creates a headache for testing and many times the software doesn't work as intended according to specifications. We need to create test files with all specification based combinations of data.

The client will not provide all combinations of the data so please don't go there.

**What we are looking for is a utility or a way to define what data we need to create and the format for that data.**

I have searched around and the only utilities (Spawner, forSQL, Red-Gate, etc) that are available only target the databases for generating data except for spawner which generates delimited files as well.

May be I am not searching the right terms, if anyone can guide me in the right direction or provide a specific solution.

Comment: After trying out different applications, I came to the conclusion that the best way to achieve my goal is to use utilities like Spawner, forSQL, Red-Gate to fill up databases and then write a utility on top of the database which will generate the format that is required for testing.

Answer (score 1):

First, permutations is probably the wrong question.  You probably want something like combinatorial testing, unless you have either a very small data set or you have the ability to run bazillions of test cases.

Try using these search phrases (prioritized/ordered):

- Pairwise testing (note that most tools do more than just data *pairs*).
- All-pairs testing
- Combination test generation
- Combinatorial test data
- Test data generators

Or try looking at these tools (and similar ones)

- http://hexawise.com/?page_id=805/
- http://www.satisfice.com/tools.shtml
- http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/53

Second, it sounds like you have more than one problem here:

- Client isn't providing something you need.  Either you are blaming them for not doing your job (testing involves creative work), or they're a risky client.  Either way, it's your problem.
- Are you doing strictly specification-based testing?  Because frankly, sometimes the specifications aren't the be-all, end-all rule for what informs your tests.  Read this: http://www.developsense.com/blog/2012/07/few-hiccupps/ (and note that specifications only fall under the "claims" heuristic)

Finally, you should be warned that aiming for pairwise coverage (or any particular type of coverage) might distract you from testing what's important.  For completeness, I suggest reading these:

- [Pairwise Testing (developsense blog) - focus on the section "Postscript 2007"](http://www.developsense.com/pairwiseTesting.html)
- [Pairwise Testing: A Best Practice that Isn't](http://www.testingeducation.org/wtst5/PairwisePNSQC2004.pdf)

Comment: Not being a tester myself pair wise testing is new to me. Looking into what you have discussed. Thank you.

Comment: Also beware of overusing or misusing any test approach: http://www.testingeducation.org/wtst5/PairwisePNSQC2004.pdf "Pairwise Testing: A Best Practice that Isn't"